# Python: Continuing through code after error

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm trying to create a program that will iterate through an array of IP addresses and connect to various cisco devices. The "ipArray" variable was defined on a different page and it's pulling in data from an excel spreadsheet.

So far, the code itself is working, but I added in some fake addresses so I could test a try/except clause and continue the program if one of the addresses isn't reachable, but I'm having trouble getting the function to continue iterating through the loop once it encounters the error. I've attempted to put the code block located under Try: in the Else: field, but it seems the function just stops entirely after it fails the first time. How would I be able to continue this code once encountering the error?

```
def backupAll(): 
    try:
        for element in ipArray:
            wRouter = {

                "device_type": "cisco_ios",
                "ip": element,
                "username": 'test',
                "password": 'cisco',
                "secret": 'cisco',

            }
            c = ConnectHandler(**wRouter)
            c.enable()
            h = c.send_command("show run | inc hostname")  ### 
            hostName = str(h)
            output1 = c.send_command("show run")
            save_file = open(hostName + '.txt', 'w')
            save_file.write(output1)
            save_file.close()
            c.disconnect()
            print(hostName + ' Complete')
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        pass
    else:
        pass
    finally:
        pass
```

Comment: You should try to put the try/except block around the actual code that will produce the exception, not the entire for loop.

Comment: Yup! That did it!

Comment: Don't catch `Exception`. Catch only the specific type of exception you expect to occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to put the `try/except` in the loop block!

```
def backupAll():
    for element in ipArray:
        wRouter = {

            "device_type": "cisco_ios",
            "ip": element,
            "username": 'test',
            "password": 'cisco',
            "secret": 'cisco',

        }
        try:
            c = ConnectHandler(**wRouter)
            c.enable()
            h = c.send_command("show run | inc hostname")  ### 
            hostName = str(h)
            output1 = c.send_command("show run")
            save_file = open(hostName + '.txt', 'w')
            save_file.write(output1)
            save_file.close()
            c.disconnect()
            print(hostName + ' Complete')
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
```